# error deploying resources on azure using terraform cloud

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-storage, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-cloud

I have deployed resources on Microsoft Azure using terraform. I'm using azure storage account container to save my terraform states. I tried to configure terraform cloud to automate the deployment but I get this error.

```
Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/{SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/resourceGroups/msk-stage-keyvault" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_resource_group" for more information.
with module.keyvault.azurerm_resource_group.msk-keyvault
on ../../modules/az-keyvault/main.tf line 2, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "msk-keyvault":
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "msk-keyvault" {
```

It seems that terraform cloud is not using my backend state in my provider.tf. How do I make terraform cloud use my backend state in provider.tf.

**My Backend Provider**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.91.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "msk-configurations"
    storage_account_name = "mskconfigurations"
    container_name       = "key-vault"
    key                  = "stage.tfstate"
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = var.subscription
  tenant_id       = var.ternant_id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like your main.tf has already existing keyvault state.
   So Initially please check if you have already  configured  keyvault resource  in main.tf file or if you have already imported the state.

- If its already present in main.tf file , and if you are again giving it in the backend , please try to remove the one from main.tf file and then execute again.

Also please note that terraform backend needs azure storage account credentials before hand in order to  store into the tfstate.

- So please avoid creating storage simultaneously all account, container and then the keyvault resource to tfstate.
- So if  storage account is already created first , then terraform can refer it later in backend.

**To preconfigure the storage account and container :**

*Example:*

**1.    Create storage account and container one after the other instead in the same file:**

```
provider "azurerm" { 
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "resourcegroupname"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "<yourstorageaccountname>"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS" 
}
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example" {
  name                  = "newterraformcont"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}
```

- Then create the msk-keyvault resource group and store the tfstate in container.
- This is my already created state file in terraform (terraform.tf)
  [image]

  ```
    provider "azurerm" { 
      features {}
    }
    terraform {
      # Configure Terraform State Storage
      backend "azurerm" {
        resource_group_name  = "<resourcegroup>"
        storage_account_name = "<storage-earliercreated>"
        container_name       = " newterraformcont "
        key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
      }
    }

   resource "azurerm_resource_group" " msk-keyvault" {
    name = "<msk-keyvault>"
    location = "west us"
     }
  ```

**Reference:**

1. [azurerm_resource_group | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform
   Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group)
2. [https://www.jorgebernhardt.com/terraform-backend](https://www.jorgebernhardt.com/terraform-backend-azure/#:%7E:text=%20How%20to%20store%20the%20Terraform%20state%20file,created%20in%20the%20previous%20step%2C%20you...%20More%20)